# MS Word Add-in won't debug in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-word, add-in

I developed a Microsoft Word Add-in in Visual Studio using `VSTO`. I can debug the Add-in/Word on several computers using VS. However, on two company issued laptops, debugging stops with the following log right after the Word splash screen appears.

```
'WINWORD.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
The program '[2836] WINWORD.EXE: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
```

So far the only thing I could find is that the exit code relates to a buffer overflow. I'm wondering if some preinstalled company software could be causing the issue. I can install and run my add-in with the generated installer, so the problem is focused on debugging in VS.

Comment: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_does_the_exception_unknown_software_exception_0xc0000409_occurred_in_the_application_at_location_0x07888247_mean check out this site for explanation sounds like you have some errors handling that you did not account for in your code..

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at that page previously and it does not help. I don't think error handling is the cause for a few reasons. 1. Debugging doesn't even reach the initialization method for my add-in, so none of my code is ever run (as I can tell). 2. The console does not print any errors or stack traces, just the exit code. 3. I've enabled breakpoints on all exceptions. 4. Error handling (or lack there of) should not act differently between two different computers.

Comment: if it never hits your code at initialization.. then isn't there something wrong or are you saying something else is causing the error what happens if you use F11 to start running the application.. ? it's hard to see / tell without having access to your actual code as well.. do you use GAC at all ..?

Comment: Yes there's something wrong, but I think something else is causing the issue because it never reaches my add-in initialization and because debugging works on most systems, but not my company's laptops. And I'm not using GAC.

Comment: I am using slightly different versions of Word but I dont think that would cause the problem. Failing version: 14.0.6106.5005. Working version: 14.0.6129.5000

Comment: Actually it would believe it or not.. you probably have some Method Collision going on.. I just ran into this issue doing work over at the DOD when I first noticed the same issue you are and I decided to implement namespace Aliasing to resolve this

Comment: Is there a way to see if Method Collision is happening? Also, I'm not sure where I could start doing namespace Aliasing, since the project is pretty large (500+ classes)